# Mapping multiple props in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to render a child component by mapping multiple props at the same time. What I'd like to do is:

```
const Parent = props => {
  const whatever = props.(***need to pass both props***).map((firstProp, secondProp)  => (
    <Child
      key={//}
      firstProp={firstProp}
      secondProp={secondProp}
    />
  )); 

  return (
    <div>
      {whatever}
    </div>
  );
}
```

What's the right way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply map over the first array and using index, get details of the second

```
const Parent = props => {
     const whatever = props.firstPropsArray.map((firstProp, index)  => (
         <Child
             key={//}
             firstProp={firstProp}
             secondProp={secondPropsArray[index]}
         />
      )); 

  return (
        <div>
           {whatever}
        </div>
     );
}
```

else you can preprocess the array to generate an array with values from both the props

```
const Parent = props => {
     const mergedProps = props.firstPropsArray.map((first, index) => ([first, secondPropsArray[index]]));
     const whatever = mergedProps.map(([firstProp, secondProp])  => (
         <Child
             key={//}
             firstProp={firstProp}
             secondProp={secondProp}
         />
      )); 

  return (
        <div>
           {whatever}
        </div>
     );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you map an array you get the second argument as am index of the array.Instead you can do like this

```
const Parent = props => {
  const whatever = props.(***need to pass both props***).map((firstProp, i)  => (
    <Child
      key={//}
      firstProp={firstProp}
      secondProp={secondProp[i]}
    />
  )); 

  return (
    <div>
      {whatever}
    </div>
  );
```